# How to do a complex MAX() and GROUP BY in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am concerned about 2 tables `AUF_KOPF` is order header and `AUF_POS` is order items.

I want to get the maximum last date that a product was used on an order item within an order. The product ID is stored in `AUF_POS.GLAS1`, `AUF_POS.GLAS2` or `AUF_POS.GLAS3`.

I have created this query which only checks `AUF_POS.GLAS1`:

```
Select Max(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT),
  AUF_POS.GLAS1
From AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join AUF_POS AUF_POS On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = AUF_POS.AUF_NR
Group By AUF_POS.GLAS1
Order By AUF_POS.GLAS1
```

Results:

```
MAX(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT)    GLAS1
07/11/2016  1
06/11/2016  2
03/11/2016  3
09/11/2016  4
07/11/2016  5
```

Problem is that product ID `1` may have been used more recently than `07/11/2016` at another position in an order `AUF_POS.GLAS2` or `AUF_POS.GLAS3`.

Is it possible to do `OR`, or what is the best method to write this? I would like to stay away from having 3 `SELECT` and then merging them as that seems messy.

Example `AUF_KOPF` rows:

```
AUF_NR  ERFASS_DAT
1609183 06/01/2016
1609184 06/01/2016
1609185 06/01/2016
1609187 06/01/2016
1609188 06/01/2016
```

Example `AUF_POS` rows:

```
AUF_NR  AUF_POS GLAS1   GLAS2   GLAS3
1609183 4   4   9   0
1609184 5   4   9   0
1609185 6   4   9   0
1609187 7   4   9   0
1609188 8   4   9   0
```

Desired output in this instance would show all products as `06/01/2016`, but with more data it would show the latest date, at any position, that the product ID was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` which shouldn't over complicate (besides the longer code)

```
Select Max(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT),
       AUF_POS.GLAS
From AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join (SELECT AUF_NR,GLAS1 as glas FROM AUF_POS UNION ALL
              SELECT AUF_NR,GLAS2         FROM AUF_POS UNION ALL
              SELECT AUF_NR,GLAS3         FROM AUF_POS) AUF_POS
  On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = AUF_POS.AUF_NR
Group By AUF_POS.GLAS
Order By AUF_POS.GLAS
```

Comment: @mathguy It wasn't a typo, it's necessary for the join .

Comment: Ugh - sorry, you are right. I don't know what I was thinking! (Actually I do, I thought you were going with the qualified names as he had in the original.... but still)

Comment: It's OK, these names are causing confusion, colums, aliases and tables all being called with the same name, even I got lost in my own code :P @mathguy